# Angular animations not working when style added by [ngStyle]

Tags: html, angular

I am new to Angular animations and maybe I am missing something. I am using `ngStyle` to display or hide text on hover. I want to smoothly enter the screen if the text displays. Well, maybe there is another approach for the same hover effect without using `ngStyle`. Here are the parts of the code.
TS:

```
@Component({
animations: [
trigger('EnterLeave', [
    state('flyIn', style({ transform: 'translateX(0)' })),
    transition(':enter', [
      style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }),
      animate('0.5s 300ms ease-in')
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
      animate('1.5s ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }))
    ])
  ]),
  ]
})
```

HTML:

```
...



<a class="mid-tranparent" (click)="isItOpen(target, 'a')"
            (mouseenter)="hover1=true" (mouseleave)="hover1=false"
            >

            <g>
                <use class="" xlink:href="#avgrMP4mt" opacity="1" 
                 >
                </use>
            </g>
            </a>

           <a class="back-tranparent" (click)="isItOpen(target, 'b')"
           (mouseenter)="hover2=true" (mouseleave)="hover2=false"
          >

            <g>
                <use class="" xlink:href="#g1gjF8EUDt" opacity="1" >
                </use>
            </g>
        </a>

...

<div class="galas" [ngStyle]="{display: hover2==true  ? 'block' : 'none' }" [@EnterLeave]="'flyIn'">
    <h1>Elektrinis dviratis</h1>
    <h2>su varikliu gale</h2>
</div>
<div class="vidurys" [ngStyle]="{display: hover1==true  ? 'block' : 'none'}" [@EnterLeave]="'flyIn'">
    <h1>Elektrinis dviratis</h1>
    <h2>su varikliu centrinėje ašyje</h2>
</div>
<div class="priekis" [ngStyle]="{display: hover3==true  ? 'block' : 'none' }" [@EnterLeave]="'flyIn'">
    <h1>Elektrinis dviratis</h1>
    <h2>su varikliu priekyje</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changed ngStyle to *ngIf. Now html code looks like that:

```
<div class="text-heading">
    <h1 class="text-h1" *ngIf="welcome" [@fadeInOut] [@EnterLeave]="'flyIn'">Paverskite savo dviratį į elektra varomu</h1>
    <h1 class="text2-h1" *ngIf="!welcome" [@fadeInOut]>Elektra varomo dviračio rinkiniai</h1>
</div>
<div class="galas" *ngIf="hover1" [@EnterLeave]="'textBack'">
    <h1>Elektrinis dviratis</h1>
    <h2>su varikliu gale</h2>
</div>
<div class="vidurys" *ngIf="hover2" [@EnterLeave]="'textBack'">
    <h1>Elektrinis dviratis</h1>
    <h2>su varikliu centrinėje ašyje</h2>
</div>
<div class="priekis" *ngIf="hover3" [@EnterLeave]="'textBack'">
    <h1>Elektrinis dviratis</h1>
    <h2>su varikliu priekyje</h2>
</div>
```